# Opening a file from spring URL Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jstl

I have looked around for the solution but cant find any solution.

I am storing a file in me local drive and storing path of that file in my mongoDB, 
after retrieving the path I want to give URL the path from DB. When I click on that URL that path should opent that related file.
My codes are as

Data in db as:

```
"filePath" : "C:/myfiles/Resume_Vipul.docx"
```

accessing it in front end as:

```
<c:forEach var="ser" items="${services}" varStatus="status">
<td class="text-center"><a href='<spring:url value="${ser.filePath}" />'>file</a></td>
</c:forEach>
```

when I click on the Url it gives me error as:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/myfiles/Resume_Vipul.docx
```

What is the correct way of performing this action.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a servlet mapping to your directory in your `web.xml` and use the mapping alias in place your `${ser.filePath}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send a request to the controller taking the file name as parameter and send back the bytes as response, something like this,

```
ServletContext cntx= req.getServletContext();
  // Get the absolute path of the image
  String filename = cntx.getRealPath("Images/button.png");
  // retrieve mimeType dynamically
  String mime = cntx.getMimeType(filename);
  if (mime == null) {
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    return;
  }

  resp.setContentType(mime);
  File file = new File(filename);
  resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
  OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

  // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
   int count = 0;
   while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
     out.write(buf, 0, count);
  }
out.close();
in.close();
```

Accessing the local resources from the client side is I think not a good idea. Consider making a separate request for this to the server. In your case, you can send the resource path as `String` parameter to the server.

Comment: I will try to implement this